How to query frequently a MultiMap in Hazelcast?
I am using Hazelcast 5, for most of our use cases IMaps were satisfactory. However I have an IMap where the value is a Collection currently, so I am looking to switch that to MultiMap.
This map is queried frequently so to avoid a lot of network roundtrips I am using either QueryCaches or the getAll method. Unfortunately there is no QueryCache, neither getAll implemented for MultiMaps in Hazelcast.
Did anyone have similar issues in the past? If so, what are the recommended workarounds (if there is any at all)?

The Multimap's API is not as rich as IMap. So I am afraid there is no good solution to what are asking
